# numpy.correlate: Relation between full and valid

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, cross-correlation

I am using numpy.correlate on two sets of data both 20000 values big.

The documentation indicates:

> mode : {‘full’, ‘valid’, ‘same’}, optional ‘full’:
>
> By default, mode is ‘full’. This returns the convolution at each point
>   of overlap, with an output shape of (N+M-1,). At the end-points of the
>   convolution, the signals do not overlap completely, and boundary
>   effects may be seen.
>
> ‘same’: Mode same returns output of length max(M, N). Boundary effects
>   are still visible.
>
> ‘valid’: Mode valid returns output of length max(M, N) - min(M, N) +
>   1. The convolution product is only given for points where the signals overlap completely. Values outside the signal boundary have no effect

Following these explanations, I expect for my sets that the "valid" option would give me the same value as the one obtained by taking the value number 20000 returned using the "full" option since only for this value the sets superimpose. However these two values are different.

Can someone explain how it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Python indexing starts at zero rather than 1. You want index 19999 rather than 20000:

```
x = np.random.randn(20000)
y = np.random.randn(20000)

np.correlate(x, y, 'valid')[0]
# -29.778322045152521

np.correlate(x, y, 'full')[19999]
# -29.778322045152521
```

Comment: Thank you ... I think it is time for a nap.